# How to inject more dependencies in angularjs controller?

Tags: angularjs

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.factory("one", function() {});
app.factory("two", function() {});
app.factory("three", function() {});
app.factory("four", function() {});
app.factory("five", function() {});
app.controller("myController", function($scope, one, two, three, four, five)
{

});
```

Instead of injecting the 5 services cumulatively into the controller is there a way to inject those dependencies in a single shot ?

Say I have 50 plus services/factory in my angular app how to inject all these into my controller ?

Comment: are you really using 50 services in every controller?

Comment: No, I'm using one controller

Comment: I agree with @Claies, if you're using a lot of injection in any provider, you might need to rethink some things. It's similar to when I'd see backbone apps with this gigantic dependency list.

Comment: are you saying you only have a single page (one controller) and you are displaying data from 50+ different services in that single page?  That must be a very busy screen....

Comment: Is there any alternative in injecting more dependencies to a single controller instead of providing as a parameters to controller

Comment: this is a very classic example of the XY Problem... http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.  You have an issue, and a possible solution (50 dependencies) which might solve it.  Instead of asking about the issue and getting assistance, you are asking about the possible solution (50 dependencies) which probably wouldn't be necessary if your issue was solved efficiently.

Comment: means there's no alternate way in injecting more dependencies to controller ? the only possible solution is injecting through a controller parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the comments above are making good points. The main point being, if you have 50 dependencies on your controller, you need to rethink your architecture.

That said, you've asked for alternative means for injecting dependencies and so here's one solution.

[**`$inject` property annotation**](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

Using this mechanism you could theoretically inject any number of dependencies and then access them through the `arguments` collection within the controller.

**It's a horrible idea.**

```
var Controller = function () {
 console.log(arguments[0]) // $scope
};

Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'one', 'two', 'three'];
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9qf6arw/